# Keras model taking forerver to train with dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, keras, large-data, dask

I m working with large dataset having low memory and I got introduced to Dask dataframe. What I understood from the docs that Dask does not load whole dataset into memory . instead it created multiple threads which will fetch the records from disk on demand basis. So I suppose keras model with having batch size = 500, it should only have 500 records in the memory at the training time. but when I start training. it takes forever.May be I am doing something wrong.please suggest.

shape of training data: 1000000 * 1290

```
import glob
import dask.dataframe
paths_train = glob.glob(r'x_train_d_final*.csv')

X_train_d = dd.read_csv('.../x_train_d_final0.csv')
Y_train1 = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train.iloc[,1], num_classes)
batch_size = 500
num_classes = 2
epochs = 5

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(645, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(1290,),kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
#model.add(Dense(20, activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=Adam(decay=0),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train_d.to_records(), Y_train,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                verbose=1,
                class_weight = {0:1,1:6.5},
                shuffle=False)
```

Comment: can you upload the csv file ?

Comment: It won't be possible since I am not working on an open project.

Comment: then describe the csv file. numbe of rows and number of columns.

Comment: also add the full code.

Comment: added both full code and dimenstions

Comment: have you tried to normalize the input data ? it is normal to take too long since you have 1000000 samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today Keras does not know about Dask dataframes or arrays.  I suspect that it is just converting the dask object into the equivalent Pandas or Numpy object instead.

If your Keras model can be trained incrementally then you could solve this problem using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) and some for loops.

Eventually it would be nice to see the Keras and Dask projects learn more about each other to facilitate these workloads without excess work.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `fit_generator()` from [Sequential model](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) with generator or with a [Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) instance. Both provide a proper way to load only a portion of data.

Keras docs provide an excellent example:

```
def generate_arrays_from_file(path):
    while 1:
        f = open(path)
        for line in f:
            # create Numpy arrays of input data
            # and labels, from each line in the file
            x, y = process_line(line)
            yield (x, y)
        f.close()

model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_file('/my_file.txt'),
                    steps_per_epoch=1000, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Exactly what I need without the overkill of various other libraries!